# License that encourages improvements to the original version rather than own forks?

Tags: licensing, api, interfaces, standardization

I'm looking for a license that should encourage changes to my original open source rather than encouraging forks and uncontrolled random redistribution. This is because of the nature of the code; it's just API definition (does not contain implementation of any kind) whose ultimate goal is precisely maintaining it consistent. I don't want to limit forks (I'll be using Github) but I want to make sure, if possible, that API stays a convention/standard. What are my options?

Comment: License is a document which is not meant to be a source of motivation (encouraging improvements), but rather a way to permit or deny something. You need something like manifesto or motivational speech to encourage people.

Comment: I know. But maybe there was a way to formalize that into a license; I tried to ask...

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way, but what's the point of doing that? Motivation should not be formalized because it just doesn't work this way. People usually write `CONTRIBUTING.md` type of files for this reason ([example](https://github.com/HoTT/book/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)).

Comment: The BSD 3-clause license requires others to get approval before using the product name. That might help establish an official name for the API. But what would be the advantage be for someone to create a different version of an API anyway? Wouldn't that imply they create something incompatible?

Comment: @Kwebble because https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: The Artistic License was created to give the original creator some amount of “artistic control” over the project while still being free software. In practice it's only used for the perl interpreter and Perl modules as a dual license together with the GPL. However, it's not very well liked by most FLOSS supporters, and the GPL is a much more mature and reliable alternative. The reality is that most software doesn't get forked unless the creator stops maintaining the project or doesn't accept patches.

Comment: This sounds like the [history](http://blog.codinghorror.com/responsible-open-source-code-parenting/) [of](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-future-of-markdown/) [Markdown](http://blog.codinghorror.com/standard-flavored-markdown/)...

Comment: It might be possible if you placed the API and the implementation under two different licenses. E.g. the API under some license similar to CC BY-ND (only unmodified versions may be redistributed) for the API and headers, and BSD license for the implementation itself.